# Data cleaning action button into Shiny App not working

Tags: r, shiny

My code is able to upload the csv / text file but not able to clean the data when i press the 'clean' action button. I am not sure what is the issue, when I tried it in both data table and data frame form both does not work. My code's purpose is for the user to:

1. upload file
2. press clean to clean the data
3. download cleaned file

Help would be much appreciated!

Data table form:

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)
runApp(shinyApp(

  ui=(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Clean your data!"),

  mainPanel(
    fileInput("file", "Upload file"),
    actionButton("Go", "Clean!"),

    DT::dataTableOutput("df_data_out"),
    downloadButton("downloadData","Download")
  )
)),
server <- function(input, output){
  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data <- as.data.table(data)
  })
  eventReactive(input$Go, {
    dt <- myData()
    dt <- as.data.table(dt)
    dt1 <- dt[, splitletter:=substr(DocRef,1,1)]
    dt2 <- dt1[splitletter == "B" | splitletter == "I"]
    dt3 <- dt2[DocDate <= 20171231 & DocDate >= 20160101]
    dt3 <- dt3[AcCurWTaxAmt>0 & HomeWTaxAmt<0, 
    HomeWTaxAmt:=abs(HomeWTaxAmt)]
    dt3 <- dt3[AcCurWTaxAmt<0 & HomeWTaxAmt>0, HomeWTaxAmt:=HomeWTaxAmt* 
(-1)]
    dt3 <- dt3[AcCurWTaxAmt==0 & HomeWTaxAmt!=0, HomeWTaxAmt:=0]
    dt3 <- dt3[AcCurWTaxAmt!=0 & HomeWTaxAmt==0, HomeWTaxAmt:=NA]
    dt4 <- na.omit(dt3)
    dt4 <- dt4[, AcCrAmt := AcCrIsMinus1 * AcCurWTaxAmt]
    dt4 <- dt4[, splitletter:= NULL]
  })
  output$df_data_out <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(myData())})
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() { 
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(myData(), file)
    })

}))
```

Data frame form:

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui=(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Clean your data!"),

    mainPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload file"),
      actionButton("Go", "Clean!"),

      tableOutput("df_data_out"),
      downloadButton("downloadData","Download")
    )
  )),
  server <- function(input, output){
    myData <- reactive({
      inFile <- input$file
      if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
      df_data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
      df_data <- as.data.frame(df_data)
    })     
    eventReactive(input$Go, {
      dt <- myData()
      dt <- as.data.frame(data)
      dt1[, splitletter] <- substr(dt$DocRef,1,1)
      dt2 <- (dt1$splitletter == "B" | dt1$splitletter == "I")
      dt3 <- (dt2$DocDate <= 20171231 & dt2$DocDate >= 20160101)
      while(dt3$AcCurWTaxAmt>0 & dt$HomeWTaxAmt<0){
        dt3$HomeWTaxAmt <- abs(dt3$HomeWTaxAmt)   
      }
      while(dt3$AcCurWTaxAmt<0 & HomeWTaxAmt>0){
        dt3$HomeWTaxAmt <- dt3$HomeWTaxAmt*(-1)
      }
      while(dt3$AcCurWTaxAmt==0 & HomeWTaxAmt!=0){
        dt3$HomeWTaxAmt <- 0
      } 
      while(dt3$AcCurWTaxAmt!=0 & HomeWTaxAmt==0){
        dt3$HomeWTaxAmt<- NA
      } 
      dt3 <- na.omit(dt3)
      dt3[,AcCrAmt] <- dt3$AcCrIsMinus1 * dt3$HomeWTaxAmt
      dt3$splitletter <- NULL
    })

   output$df_data_out <- renderTable({
     myData()
   })
   output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

      filename = function() { 
        paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(myData(), file)
      })
}))
```

Comment: `cleanedData <- eventReactive({...})` then use `cleandata()` instead of `myData()`

Comment: thank you for your reply! but when i tried that, i obtained these errors: 

Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  138: substr
  137: eventReactiveHandler [#23]
   93: cleanedData
   92: renderTable [#45]
   91: func
   78: origRenderFunc
   77: output$df_data_out
    1: runApp

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example. It's difficult to replicate things with an that takes a `CSV` as input as we do not know what you chuck in it. Moreover you are referencing columns by name in your `eventReactive` so I assume you are always passing it a specific `CSV`.

`eventReactive` is, well, a reactive function, only it takes also takes an expression that triggers it. As such, it returns a reactive expression just like `reactive`. You are trying to use `eventReactive` like `observeEvent`.

When people click the button `eventReactive` is triggered and returns a `reactive` which you do not use. The `reactive`expression object `myData` remains unchanged. If you do not use the output of `eventReactive` in any of your outputs (i.e.: `output$df_data_out`) then the reactive never runs...

Also note that your `reactive` expressions do not have explicit `return`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select", "select data", choices = c("cars", "iris")),
  actionButton("clean", "Clean data"),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, tableOutput("original")),
    column(6, tableOutput("cleaned"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  orig_data <- reactive({
    if(input$select == "cars")
      return(cars)
    else
      return(iris)
  })

  cleaned_data <- eventReactive(input$clean, {
    orig_data() %>% 
      head(5)
  })

  output$original <- renderTable({
    orig_data()
  })

  output$cleaned <- renderTable({
    cleaned_data()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```